# RUNNING HANDLER [nova : Restart nova-libvirt container]---Failed

Tags: containers, cloud, centos7, openstack-nova

> RUNNING HANDLER [nova : Restart nova-libvirt container]...
>   this failed in deployment part of openstack

These are the commands to deploy openstack that and error comes while i run the deploy command:-

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install python-devel libffi-devel gcc openssl-devel libselinux-python
sudo yum install python-pip
sudo pip install -U pip
sudo yum install ansible
sudo pip install kolla-ansible
sudo pip install kolla-ansible --ignore-install PyYAML
sudo mkdir -p /etc/kola
sudo chown $USER:$USER /etc/kola
cp -r /usr/share/kolla-ansible/etc_examples/kolla/* /etc/kola
cp /usr/share/kolla-ansible/ansible/inventory/* .
kolla-genpwd
cp globals.yml globals.yml.old
kolla-ansible -i ./all-in-one bootstrap-servers
kolla-ansible -i ./all-in-one prechecks
kolla-ansible -i ./all-in-one deploy
kolla-ansible -i ./all-in-one deploy
```

final command which create all images and deploy openstack

The given below is the error

> RUNNING HANDLER [nova : Restart nova-libvirt container] *******************************************************************
>   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'config_json.changed | bool or nova_libvirt_confs.changed | bool or nova_libvirt_container.changed | bool or ( ceph_conf is not none and ceph_conf.changed | bool ) or ( nova_ceph_keyring is defined and nova_ceph_keyring.changed | bool ) or ( libvirt_secrets_xml is defined and libvirt_secrets_xml.changed | bool ) or ( libvirt_secrets_key is defined and libvirt_secrets_key.changed | bool )' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (config_json.changed | bool or nova_libvirt_confs.changed | bool or nova_libvirt_container.changed | bool or ( ceph_conf is not none and ceph_conf.changed | bool ) or ( nova_ceph_keyring is defined and nova_ceph_keyring.changed | bool ) or ( libvirt_secrets_xml is defined and libvirt_secrets_xml.changed | bool ) or ( libvirt_secrets_key is defined and libvirt_secrets_key.changed | bool )): 'unicode object' has no attribute 'changed'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/usr/share/kolla-ansible/ansible/roles/nova/handlers/main.yml': line 52, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Restart nova-libvirt container\n  ^ here\

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bug related to ansible < 2.8. Have a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/kolla-ansible/+bug/1835817

So check you are using ansible >= 2.8 at first.

If the error occour after a first installation or upgrading  with kolla-ansible upgrade, then try to pull down the container first using the command kolla-ansible pull